# Python Invalid Syntax after __main__:

Tags: python

Why am I getting this error on the colon when it worked previously?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# My Name hw 11

def maxArray(a):
    max = a[0]
    for element in a:
        if element > max:
            max = element
    return max
if__name__=="__main__":

array = [3,1,6,2,4,9,0] 
maxArray(array)
print max
```

I'm getting a syntax error pointing to the colon after `"__main__":`

Comment: iCodez is right. Also, Indentation of the block after `if __name__=="__main__":` should be one block to the right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four issues here:

1. You need a space after the `if`.  Otherwise, Python sees `if__name__`, which it treats as one word.  This is what is causing the error.
2. You need to indent the lines under this one so that you do not get an `IndentationError`.
3. You need to assign the return value of `maxArray` to a variable and then print that.  Otherwise, the last line will throw a `NameError` saying `max` is undefined.
4. You should not name a variable `max`.  Doing so overshadows the [built-in](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#max).

Here is how your code should look:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# My Name hw 11

def maxArray(a):
    max_ = a[0]
    for element in a:
        if element > max_:
            max_ = element
    return max_


if __name__=="__main__":
    array = [3,1,6,2,4,9,0] 
    max_ = maxArray(array)
    print max_
```

Comment: @cparnin - I don't doubt it. :)  Skill comes with experience and experience comes with time.  If you keep at something, you will eventually master it.